# Find the number of combination of 'n' together of '3n' letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of ways of selecting ***n*** letters from ***3n*** letters  which contains '***n***' ***a*** s , '***n***'  ***b*** s and the rest ***n*** letters are distinct from each other.

From the language of the problem I can easily understood that we need to select ***n*** letters.

I will categorize it into three category using 
$C(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

I will use $C(n,\ r_1)*C(n,\ r_2)*C(n,\ r_3)$,

$\ r_1$ =***a*** group, $\ r_2$ =***b*** group & $\ r_3$ =*unlike* group

Where $\ r_1+\ r_2 +\ r_3 =n$  I presume that i am on the right approach but I am not able to proceed hence forth.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What does "$n$ together of $3n$ letters" mean?  Also, what does "the rest unlike" mean?  Do you mean that the rest are neither $a$ nor $b$ or do you mean that the rest are all distinct (presumably from $a,b$ and from each other)?  Perhaps you could work the problem explicitly for, say, $n=2$ to illustrate what you have in mind.

Comment: I copied the question from a source using copy and paste option. What i understood that we have to select n letters from 3n letters which has n *a* n *b*  and n different letters.

Comment: I already framed the formula and then from that step forward I am not able to solve it

Comment: Perhaps it is a translation issue....that phrasing doesn't sound like it was written by an English speaker.  Nor do I understand your formula.  As I say, it would help if you would write out the case of $n=2$ explicitly...to illustrate your view of the question, if nothing else.

Comment: @lulu Suppose n=2, We have a,a,b,b,c,d. Then what is the number of ways of selecting two letters

Comment: I copied a question from a list of question using Copy and paste option and cross checked it before submitting, but i understood the logic behind it which i have illustrated in my write up

Comment: So you think that the odd two letters must be distinct from $a,b$ and from each other?  Ok.  Please edit the question to reflect that...it really isn't clear from what you wrote.  As to your formula, note that the $r_1$ letters that you choose from the $a's$ (and the $r_2$ that you choose from the $b's$) are all the same so there are no further choices to be made.  Of course you do need to make choices for the $r_3$.

Comment: To summarize:  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) shows you how to count the ordered triples $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ that sum to $n$.  Each such triple then gives rise to $\binom n{r_3}$ combinations of the form you want.

Comment: As I have copied the question from a question bank, i presume that if I edit it it will change the language of P&C question but I will do  editing of the question

Comment: You can leave the question as you like, but add a sentence or two discussing how you are interpreting it.  As written, I think people will waste a lot of time coming up with alternate interpretations (or, more likely, just give up).

Comment: Do you understand my comment on the way to use Stars and Bars to address the problem?

Comment: @lulu Can I use $(1+x^1+x^2+....x^n)^3$ to find the coefficient of $x^n$ which can be the answer

Comment: @lulu I know that Stars and Bars use C(n+r-1,n) option to find the result

Comment: I don't immediately see how to use generating functions to do it.  Actually, though, it is easier than Stars and Bars.  Just fix the $r_3$ term and then note that it is easy to count the pairs $(r_1,r_2)$ that sum to $n-r_3$.  But, please edit your post for clarity.  As written it is very hard to guess what it is you are asking.

Comment: @lulu I got the answer $ (n+2)2^{n-1}$ thank you for giving me the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already provided the answer in a comment: $(n+2)2^{n-1}$.

Here's an algebraic proof: There are $k+1$ ways to select $k$ a's and b's, and then there are $\binom nk$ ways to choose the distinct letters you don't select. Thus the desired count is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)\binom nk
&=&
\left[\frac\partial{\partial q}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkq^{k+1}\right]_{q=1}
\\
&=&
\left[\frac\partial{\partial q}\left(q(1+q)^n\right)\right]_{q=1}
\\
&=&
2^n+n2^{n-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Here's a combinatorial proof: The selections without b's correspond to the $2^n$ subsets of the $n$ distinct letters. (Add the right number of a's to such a subset, and you get a unique selection without b's.) Now consider the selections with at least one b. Each contains a proper subset $S$ of the $n$ distinct letters, and the number of elements not contained in $S$ is the number of choices for the non-zero number of b's to add. Thus, the choice of the non-zero number of b's corresponds to distinguishing one of the distinct letters not contained in $S$. Thus, the selections with at least one b are in bijection with the ways to distinguish one of the distinct letters ($n$ choices) and to choose a subset of the remaining distinct letters ($2^{n-1}$ choices). Hence the total number of selections is $2^n+n2^{n-1}$.